# Group by in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have dataTables I want to find null specialization of course Courses like

```
Specization     course    year

null              IT        0
null              IT        0
null             Math       0
```

IF HAVE FOLLWING QUERY IN LINQ

```
var NospecList = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where r.Field<decimal>("year") == 0 && r.Field<string>("Specization  ") == null
                  group r by r.Field<string>("course"));
```

but can not find the following result in linq

```
IT -> 2

Math -> 1
```

I want count of all course whose specialization is null

Comment: Question needs little more explanation.

Comment: Ideally, provide a short but complete example (including some sample data), nicely formatted, ready for us to help you. Currently we don't know what results you're *actually* getting, which doesn't help.

Comment: @WaqasAli: It's not much better than it was before. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and edit your question *significantly* to make it easier for us to help you. As I said before, a short but *complete* example would help massively - that's the fastest way to get an answer, even though it means more up-front work on your part.

Comment: can you make some query if you data like above

Comment: you are missing select statement

Answer (score 2):

```
var NospecList = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where r.Field<decimal>("year") == 0 && r.Field<string>("Specization  ") == null
                  group r by r.Field<string>("course") into g
                  select new {Course=g.Key, Count=g.Count()});
```

**Result:**

```
IT -> 2

Math -> 1
```

UPDATE:

If you want use it in `foreach`,just:

```
foreach(var item in NospecList )
{
   //item.Course
   //item.Count
}
```

Comment: how to use this in my program can you further explain with foraeach

Comment: NospecList .Count like this

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is missing "Select" statement. Try this.

```
var NospecList = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where r.Field<decimal>("year") == 0 && r.Field<string>("Specization  ") == null
              group r by r.Field<string>("course") into grp
              select new {Course = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()});
```

Comment: You had missed `}` in your `select` query. Edit your answer by changing `select new {Course = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count());` to `select new {Course = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()});`